# Push notifications not popping after android app is killed

Tags: android, push-notification

Really its annoying, what is the use of implementing push notifications if its is not delivering to killed apps. Most apps would be killed by 3rd party apps like 360 security and Autostart manager is blocking to receive further notifications. I realized, there is an option call notification payload to deliver notifications for offline notification. But i shocked, it also behaving like earlier method. It is working when the app is foreground or background not killed. When app gets killed this method also not working. I am really disappointed as a developer, it seems no scope for being an android developer, felt cornered.

Is there anyway to deliver notifications when app is offline/killed?

My Notification Payload looked like this

```
{
   to: 'registration_token', // required
   collapse_key: 'your_collapse_key', 
   data: {
       your_custom_data_key: 'your_custom_data_value'
   },
   notification: {
      title: 'Title of your push notification',
      body: 'Body of your push notification',
      click_action: 'OPEN_ACTIVITY'
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show me your receiver please

Comment: thanks @tamtom , I am using FCM. It is working fine when app is in foreground/closed but not killed. Real headache is with killed app.

Comment: @tamtom should concern about receiver when app won't wake?